# Electron.js ipc.sendSync Frezees

Tags: javascript, html, electron, ipc

Hi I'm requesting two results from the main process but when I click the button, the app keeps freezing. Even devtools is not working .

## Main.js

```
ipcMain.on('fmail', (event, arg) => {
  var fmaile = even
  var fmaila = arg  

  ipcMain.on('fpass', (event, arg) => { 
    var fpasse = event
    var fpassa = arg

    console.log(fpassa)
    console.log(fmaila)

    fmaile.returnValue = "info"
    fpasse.returnValue = "info"
  })
})
```

### Javascript

```
var datamail = ipcRenderer.sendSync('fmail', "fmail");
var datapass = ipcRenderer.sendSync('fpass', "fpass");
console.log(datamail)
console.log(datapass)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: To gain further understanding of your problem, [the node.js event loop](https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-event-loop) is a good read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-args) is pretty clear on this one:

> Sending a synchronous message will block the whole renderer process until the reply is received.

Since you don't provide a return value in your `fmail` callback, no wonder it blocks your app.

Also, I guess you wanted to register both listeners individually. What you currently have is "add listener to 'fpass' every time 'fmail' is called back"

Your code should probably look like this (but cannot tell exactly really)

```
ipcMain.on('fmail', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)
  event.returnValue = "info"
})
ipcMain.on('fpass', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)
  event.returnValue = "info"
})
console.log(
  ipcRenderer.sendSync('fmail', "fmail"),
  ipcRenderer.sendSync('fpass', "fpass")
)
```

---

Docs also mentions a more convenient alternative for such cases: Use [`invoke()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)